# Check if V is pressed in Electron (React)

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have created this event which is firing when I hold down the v key.

`globalShortcut.register('v', () => { win?.webContents.send('v-key-down'); });`

My problem with this is that if I start to hold down the v key, will the event fire again and again, but as soon as I hold down another key with the v key, will the event listener not fire.

The only solution to this problem I have been thinking about is to create an event listener for every possible key combination include the v key, but thinking about how many keys the keyboard have and all the combinations I don’t think that would be doable.

1. The key event need to be able to fire when I do not focus on the application
2. The key event need to still fire when I start to press other keys

Another solution to this problem could also maybe be to create a keydown and keyup event listener.

Feel free to let me know if you know how I could solve this problem.

I have tried to create an event listener, but it is not working how I want it too.

Comment: Tangential: creating event listeners for every key combination is iteration(s) over the keys we care about. However trivial, unlikely the best solution. Better to take a close look at what is happening in the key combo events. E.g., if there's still a "v" around in the combo event, you can run the same code as a v-by-itself event. If it's not in the key combo event, I'd explore **why** it isn't there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I appreciate it. Would you mind showing me how this would look in a script?